# Python, api requests

Tags: python, api, networking, request

I have a following question. Is there any possibility to enlarge the speed of sending the single api request. I want to send request and obtain json as a result. When i use `requests.get(url)` the time is about **150ms**.
I would like to make this time lower. My aim is to speed up single request. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: The response time is caused by a lot of factors, it maybe something on the server side and totally out of your control.

Comment: Not to be a smarta$$, but that speed is partially dictated by your network speed in reference to API requests. So you can get faster internet, which should help (but it will still be minimal bc most of the latency is held up by server side computation)

Answer (score 0):

Well according to benchmarks, urllib2 tends to be the fastest. So if you wanted to speed up your code, you could do the following:

Python 2.x:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Python 3.x:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

But as others have pointed out, this will largely depend on server and your own network.

Answer (score 0):

**GLOBAL ANSWER** ( Read These methods, beside...you can try a lot of modules that can send/receive your current data to your target server ):

1. Check your internet connection speed, pause/stop/disable all of your downloading process.
2. Disable your firewall/antivirus/os_default_defender or any kind of security programs who scan your internet protocols and suspend your net IOs for a while.
3. Check your vpn/proxy or any kind of tunneler programs! ( because they can check and suspend your connections and make your internet connection slower ).
4. Check your default DNS ips, choose The fastest DNS server in the world like google = 8.8.8.8 or others ...
5. Clean your virtual ram buffer and check your os disk IO speed ( close your heavy programs such as converter programs ... )
6. Change your programming language !!! python is good but it is not fastest language for send/receive data from www. even you can try low level programming ( for your requests pyhton use your os internal services!!this bridge can make your connection slower, you will not have this bridge if you use your os friendly langs ( like .NET langs on windows ).
7. You can compress your data to make your request faster.

**At last it depends on your target server response and your os!! linux has different net IOs handler from windows!!**

Good Luck ...